# NullPointerException while trying to access file from Cache on Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, temporary-files

I am facing a Null pointer exception while trying to access a file I create in Cache within the same application. Here is the basic flow of my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String MP4_EXT = ".mp4";
public static String PACKAGE_NAME ;
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
  context = this;
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  new MyTask(getFileFromIntent(getIntent()), context).execute();
}

private static String stripExtension(String inputName) {
  // some implementation
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
  private final String inputFilename;
  private Context mContext;
  private static final String TAG = "MyTask";

  public MyTask(String filename, Context context) {
    this.inputFilename = filename;
    this.mContext = context;
  }

@Override
protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
  if (inputFilename == null) {
    return null;
  }

  File inputFile = new File(inputFilename);
   byte[] inputBytes;
   try {
      inputBytes = Files.toByteArray(inputFile);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return null;
   }
   String outputName = stripExtension(inputFile.getName());
   File outputFile = File.createTempFile(outputName, MP4_EXT, mContext.getCacheDir());
   // code to fill up outputFile
  MediaStoreUtil.updateFile(MyActivity.this, outputFile);
  return outputFile;
}
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(File outputFile) {
   if (outputFile == null) {
   finish();
   return;
  }
  Uri uri;
  try {
    uri  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, PACKAGE_NAME, outputFile);
   } catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "Caught exception while trying to get temp file: ", e);
    return;
   }

   // code to use the video file

  };
 }
}
```

The code if failing in the line where I try to get the `uri` using the `FileProvider`. Here is the exception:

```
outputFile /data/user/0/com.example.package/cache/YI3D0496495423980834512065.mp4
Caught exception while trying to get temp file: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
at com.example.package.MyActivity$MyTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:150)
at com.example.package.MyActivity$MyTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:80)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have the following code in my manifest file:

```
<application>
 <provider>
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.package"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
  </provider>
 </application>
```

And I have added a new file to `res/xml/file_paths.xml` which contains:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <cache-path name="videos" path="" />
 </paths>
```

Comment: `public static Context CONTEXT;` It should not be public. And not static. And name it context.

Comment: can you please share your manifest file

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of exception log too so it can help us more

Comment: My Manifest file does not have a `<provider>` element in it. Is that the problem? Also, I don't have a paths xml file pointing to the location of the directory storing the video. Can someone point to an example or share a snippet of code which have this functionality. Further, is there an easier way of doing this - I believe that since I am reading and writing in the same application, the `File` object should have just worked.

Comment: Yes. You need to implement that all of course.

Comment: yes and next time please post full stack trace log too so everyone can help you little bit fast

Comment: Link to android docs for storing camera picture [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics).

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I have modified the post with all the information you asked for... added the full exception stack, added the Manifest and the file_paths.xml file. The error has not changed from what I reported previously.

Comment: Change `path=""` to `path="."`.

Comment: Is `PACKAGE_NAME` equal to `"com.example.package"` ?